# PyGtk, What are The Hidden Chars in TextView?

Tags: pygtk

i meet a problem when i used `get_text(start_iter, end_iter, include_hidden_chars)` method of `Gtk TextBuffer` object. i didn't understand include_hidden_chars arg what it is and what it does?
can you give simple example about hidden chars in Gtk TextView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some invisible text in the text buffer by using a text mark that sets the "invisible" property to true [1]

When you use the get_text method of the buffer you can decide if the method should or shouldn't include the hidden text in the return value

[1] https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextTag.html#GtkTextTag--invisible

Comment: Thanks. do you know Why are there such hidden chars ?